# Conditional binary operator expected: syntax error near `$1'

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to run simple code block.
It gives error on fourth line as "**syntax error near `$1'**"

=~ means Matches Regular Expression

How should I use '$1' variable with this operator?

Here is my code:

```
if [[ $1 -gt 3 ]] && [[ $1 -lt 7 ]]
then
echo "$1 is between 3 and 7"
elif [[ $1 =~ "Jeff"]] || [[ $1 =~ "Roger" ]] || [[ $1 =~ "Brian" ]]
then
echo "$1 works in the Data Science Lab"
else
echo "You entered: $1, not what I was looking for.."
fi
```

Comment: The first test (whether it's between 3 and 7) only makes sense if `$1` is a number; this test will mostly technically work, but since `$1` is sometimes expected to have non-numeric values, you should test whether that test even makes sense, before testing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very funny indeed. You've typed the first condition in that line as `[[ $1 =~ "Jeff"]]`, so without a space between `"Jeff"` and `]]` bash interprets them as a single string, which is obviously not your pattern, and the whole parse fails and line structure crashes. If you add that space:

```
if [[ $1 =~ "Jeff" ]] || [[ $1 =~ "Roger" ]] || [[ $1 =~ "Brian" ]]
```

then it works... seemingly...

Comment: If you are using a regex anyway, the various strings could be combined into a single regex like `if [[ $1 =~ ^(Jeff|Roger|Brian)$ ]]`

Comment: @tripleee Sure (and even if not regex, conditions still can be combined into a single disjunction).